# How to run shell commands from a Mac/MacRuby application?

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, macruby

I am trying to write a little MacRuby status bar application that runs a command from the command line and displays the output. I don't know how to do this. How can I do this from my Mac application?

**Update:** The other thing that it might need to do is ask for an administrator password. Sometimes when I run this script from the command line, it asks for my password. I don't know how I would prompt the user for their password (or embed the shell so they could type it directly).

Comment: What exactly does your script do?

Comment: Eventually, it's going to be a GUI wrapper for [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). So I will need to run `vagrant up` and see the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Cocoa and MacRuby, utilize NSTask. Example that executes *ls -la* and prints output:

```
framework 'Cocoa'

task = NSTask.alloc.init
task.setLaunchPath("/bin/ls")

arguments = NSArray.arrayWithObjects("-l", "-a", nil)
task.setArguments(arguments)

pipe = NSPipe.pipe
task.setStandardOutput(pipe)

file = pipe.fileHandleForReading

task.launch

data = file.readDataToEndOfFile

string = NSString.alloc.initWithData(data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
puts "Command returned: "
puts string
```

Unfortunately, including admin privileges is no trivial task, especially using MacRuby.  Have a look at the SecurityFoundation framework, and this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html).  Essentially, you need to call

```
AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(...)
```

with a configured AuthorizationRef, path of the tool to execute, flags, arguments.  There is a useful example [here](http://code.google.com/p/bdunagan/source/browse/trunk/BDAuthorize/AuthHelperTool.m) (in ObjC) showing how this works.

Comment: Thanks! That helps! From what I can tell, this will block until finished. Is there a way to asynchronously run the command and update the UI as each line is output?

Comment: To update asynchronously, you can either use _readInBackgroundAndNotify_, or monitor StandardOutput in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use backticks:

```
output = `cd ~ && ls`
puts output # or assign to a label, textbox etc.
```

If your command needs admin privileges to run, it won't run the command at all and won't return a response.

Comment: That looks like it might work, but I need to come up with a solution that allows me to prompt the user for password. When I run from the command line, sometimes, halfway through the script, it will try to do something that requires administrator privileges, so it will prompt the user for password.

Comment: how about attempting to read a protected system file inside your objective-c main() method just before macruby_main(). That will force the authorization.